# Differences between a list of values and as.list of a dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

The problem is that in the next example a query gives me no result if I use a list created by filtering a dataset, while it works if I create a list with the same result, but written as strings.

I have this dataset of soccer teams. I should take the matches played by a South team (Napoli, Cagliari, Crotone and Palermo). I've tried in two ways:

1. Creating a list by filtering football_ratings dataframe

```
south_teams<- football_ratings %>%
  filter(region=="South") %>%
  select(HomeTeam) %>%
  as.list()

# "Napoli"   "Cagliari" "Crotone"  "Palermo"
```

2. Creating a list of Strings with the same result

```
south_teams<- c("Napoli","Cagliari","Crotone","Palermo")
```

If I filter a dataset with the second list I obtain a table of 140 rows. If I try to do the same with the first list, I obtain a table of 0 rows.

If I filter a dataset with the second list I obtain a table of 140 rows. If I try to do the same with the first list, I obtain a table of 0 rows.

```
football_matches %>%
  filter(HomeTeam %in% south_teams | AwayTeam %in% south_teams)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have a vector of values and not `list`.  In the first case with `==`, you are doing elementwise comparison and recycling happens

Comment: `list`s are `vector`s but `vector`s are not `list`s. `c` creates a vector not a `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's pretend that this is your first list

```
south_teams <- tibble(HomeTeam = c("Napoli","Cagliari","Crotone","Palermo")) %>% 
  as.list()
```

If we look at results we see

```
south_teams
# $`HomeTeam`
# [1] "Napoli"   "Cagliari" "Crotone"  "Palermo"
```

So you need `south_teams$HomeTeam`, not `south_teams` 
For example:

```
"Napoli" %in% south_teams
# [1] FALSE
"Napoli" %in% south_teams$HomeTeam
# [1] TRUE
```